# VirtualBox won't start any machines

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

it will display this message if I try to start a machine

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Compilers.
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I have already turned "Intel virtualization technology" on and checked to see if hyper-v is turned off. what else can I do?
I have also checked that my CPU has sse4 and vt-x support.
I am running VirtualBox on a Windows 10 PC

Comment: https://techsupportwhale.com/not-in-a-hypervisor-partition/

Comment: What are the exact models of your computer, motherboard & CPU?

Comment: Is the VirtualBox native driver loaded and running (`sc.exe query vboxdrv`)? The 2nd line of your message indicates that VirtualBox tried using the Hyper-V (WHP) platform (which it now supports, though at non-ideal performance), which implies that it failed to access its own virtualization platform first.

Comment: Oh, and do you have Intel HAXM installed (e.g. for Android Studio)? That's a hypervisor as well, and likely to conflict with VirtualBox.

Comment: @user1686 sc query for both vboxdrv and intelhaxm returned the following:
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Comment: @harrymc motherboard: z170-k CPU: i7-6700  I assume you meant laptop model by computer but I have a pc

Comment: The term "computer" is supposed to cover both desktop & laptop ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can find about your motherboard,
you should enable the following options in the BIOS:

```
Advanced -> Platform Misc Configuration
  PCI Express Native Power Management -> Enabled
  Native ASPM -> Enabled

Advanced -> CPU Configuration
  Intel Virtualization Technology -> Enabled

Advanced -> System Agent (SA) Configuration
  VT-d -> Enabled
```

Comment: thank you that solved the problem.